# Displaying weather from an API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the weatherunderground api to display weather information.

When running my code I get the following message.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'parsed_json['location']['city']')

I'm not sure why this is or how to fix this. I am new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/dddb7758c5d626fc/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {
  var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
  var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
  alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
  }
  });
});
```

After updating my api it works but I still get the same message in the console

Comment: Is this a json API or jsonp API ?

Answer (score 1):

your success function means that you have reach your api, but this API can returns you an error !

See what i've got when i go to the url :

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  }
        ,
    "error": {
        "type": "invalidkey"
        ,"description": "this key is not valid due to exceeding rate plan"
    }
    }
}
```

So check your API key, and check if errors exists before doing anything. And same, always check everything, so event if there is no errors, check if values exists before trying to do something else with it !

Comment: I changed my api but still having the same problem

Comment: use something like "postman" to test your api calls. And then write me back the response from your api call

Comment: I get all the information I need, must be something on my end

Comment: it now works but I still get that error in the console

Comment: i don't have enough informations... But all i can say, is that you seem to be trying to access an undefined value as an object, so before doing "var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];", do an : 
"if(parsed_json['location']['city'] !== undefined)

Comment: sadly it didn't

Comment: then try if(parsed_json['location']['city'] !== "undefined")

Comment: it was something to do with a search I have added

Answer (score 0):

Always check for errors:

so instead of use the data right away as you do, try

```
success : function(parsed_json) {
  if(parsed_json.response.error) {
    // found error
    alert('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(parsed_json.response.error);
    return;
  }

  // all good!
  var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
  var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
  alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
}
```

Here's a live example:

```js
$(function() {
  getWeather();
});

function getWeather() {
  var serviceUrl = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/dddb7758c5d626fc/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json";
  
  $.ajax({
    // The url
    url: serviceUrl,
 
    // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
    jsonp: "callback",
 
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",
 
    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {      
      console.log( response ); // server response
      
      var msg = "";
      if(response.response.error) {
        msg = "ERROR FOUND\n" + JSON.stringify(response.response.error);
      }
      else {
         msg = JSON.stringify(response.response);
      }
      
      $("pre").text(msg);
    }
  });  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <pre></pre>
  
</body>
</html>
```